# How stepContext.prompt() execute and move automatically to next step in waterfallDialog using BotFramework SDK V4 NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I'm using Microsoft BotBuilder V4 NodeJs SDK for bot development. I'm facing an issue where I'm recalling my waterfall dialog. Inside, one of the async step() - I'm invoking call for prompt() which is type of textPrompt. 
Here, what I'm facing an issue:
On first initial execution cycle of Waterfall Dialog - prompt() works appropriately.
But, on second call for same waterfall dialog - prompt() doesn't wait for user input text. Instead, it move automatically to next async step().

How does it move to the next async step() function in the waterfall dialog without sending another message to bot?

```
 const { ComponentDialog, TextPrompt, WaterfallDialog } = 
 require('botbuilder-dialogs');
 const { CardFactory, ActionTypes } = require('botbuilder');
 const initialId = 'Main_Dialog';
 const MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG = 'mainDWaterfallDialog';
class Main_Dialog extends ComponentDialog {
constructor(conversationState, userState, luisApplication, luisPredictionOptions) {
    super('Main_Dialog');

    this.luisRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer(luisApplication, luisPredictionOptions, true);

    this.conversationData = conversationState.createProperty("mainDialog");
    this.userProfile = userState.createProperty("mainDialog");

    // Create our bot's dialog set, adding a main dialog and their component dialogs.
    this.addDialog(new TextPrompt('PromptTextPrompt', this.waitForUserPromptValidator))
        .addDialog(new MyAdaptiveBot('MyAdaptiveBot'))
        .addDialog(new Welcome_C_Dialog('Welcome_C_Dialog'))
        .addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.introStep.bind(this),
            this.actStep.bind(this),
            this.finalStep.bind(this)
        ]));

    this.initialDialogId = MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG;
    this.query_flag = false;
    this.process_flag = false;
}


async run(turnContext, accessor) {
    const dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
    dialogSet.add(this);

    const dialogContext = await dialogSet.createContext(turnContext);
    const results = await dialogContext.continueDialog();
    if (results.status === DialogTurnStatus.empty) {
        await dialogContext.beginDialog(this.id);
    }
}

async introStep(stepContext) {
    if (this.recognizer !== undefined) {
        throw new Error('[MainDialog]: LUIS LuisRecognizer not configured properly');
    }

    return await stepContext.prompt('PromptTextPrompt', 'What can I do for you?', {retryPrompt: 'Sorry, please submit your adverse event case. Otherwise, say cancel.'});
}


async actStep(stepContext) {


        const luisResult = await this.luisRecognizer.recognize(stepContext.context);
        let switch_case = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(luisResult);

        switch (switch_case) {
            case "Greetings":
                // await turnContext.sendActivity(`Welcome to AECaseBuilder!`);
                this.query_flag = true;    // set - true query_flag
                await stepContext.beginDialog('Welcome_C_Dialog');
                break;

            case "Enquiry":
                //const user_inp = turnContext.activity.text;
                await stepContext.beginDialog('MyAdaptiveBot', null);
                this.query_flag = false;    // reset query_flag
                break;


            default:
                // Catch all for unhandled intents
                break;
        }

    return await stepContext.next();
}

async finalStep(stepContext) {

    // Restart the main dialog with a different message the second time around
    const messageText = "Whats else can I do for you?";
    return await stepContext.replaceDialog(this.initialDialogId, { restartMsg: messageText });
}
async waitForUserPromptValidator(promptContext){
    console.log(`prompt : ${promptContext.recognized.value}`);
    if(promptContext.recognized.value.trim() === ''){
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}

module.exports.Main_Dialog = Main_Dialog;




 //@File: Welcome_C_Dialog

 const { ComponentDialog, TextPrompt, WaterfallDialog } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
 const { CardFactory, ActionTypes } = require('botbuilder');

 const initialId = 'Welcome_C_Dialog';
 const welcomeCard = require('./resources/welcome_acb.json');

 class Welcome_C_Dialog extends ComponentDialog {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {*} id
     * @method - constructor()
     * @returns - void 
     */
   constructor(id){
           super(id);

           // ID of the child dialog that should be started anytime the component is started.
           this.initialDialogId = initialId;

           // Define the prompts used in this conversation flow.
           this.addDialog(new TextPrompt('textPrompt', this.waitForInputValidator));

           // Define the conversation flow using a waterfall model.
           this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(initialId,[
                       // dialog steps
                       async function(step){
                               // Clear the case information and prompt for user to submit new case intake.
                               step.values.caseInfo = {};
                               await step.context.sendActivity({
                                   text: "",
                                   attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(welcomeCard)]
                               });

                            //    return await step.prompt('textPrompt', 'Waiting for your case intake...',{ 
                            //            retryPrompt: 'Sorry, please submit your case for AECaseBuilder or say cancel.'
                            //    });
                            //    return MyAdaptiveDialog.EndOfTurn;
                               return await step.endDialog();
                       }/*, 
                       async function(step){
                               await step.context.sendActivity('received case...');
                               const resultValue = step.result;
                               //console.log(` input text: ${resultValue}`);
                               step.values.caseInfo.inputText = resultValue;

                               return await step.endDialog({inputText: resultValue});
                       }*/
           ]));

   }

   /**
    * 
    * @param {*} promptContext 
    * @method waitForInputValidator()
    * @returns true if case input received successfully. Otherwise, returs false.
    */
   async waitForInputValidator(promptContext){
           //console.log(`prompt : ${promptContext.recognized.value}`);
            if(promptContext.recognized.value.trim() === ''){
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
   }
}

exports.Welcome_C_Dialog = Welcome_C_Dialog;
```

Comment: Can you post your code for "MyAdaptiveBot" and "Welcome_C_Dialog"? When I test using your code, it largely functions correctly.

Comment: @StevenKanberg - please check updated code. I added Welcome_C_Dialog. Further, MyAdaptiveBot is still under implementation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you structuring the component dialog ("Welcome_C_Dialog") with the steps defined inside the `this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog())` call? Normally, component dialogs are designed like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/dialogs/bookingDialog.js), with the steps bound to the parent.

Comment: @StevenKanberg -  Further, I would like to update you that after executing "Welcome_C_Dialog". Still, on second call of mainDialog - waterfalldialog steps - it does not wait for user input on call of stepContext.prompt('PromptTextPrompt', ....);

Comment: @StevenKanberg - Earlier I designed it for some other input requirement to handle greeting response separately. Later, I just ended this dialog by simply - sending adaptive card.

Comment: Can you try building and calling your component dialog ("Welcome_C_Dialog") as shown [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/dialogs/bookingDialog.js)? I would like to simplify this as much as possible to better narrow down a cause.

Comment: Thanks @StevenKanberg - It worked!